# Beego framework - api project - can I have folder structure in controller folder

Tags: go, beego

I want to group my controllers in some folder structure.

Application works if controllers are directly in 'controllers' folder.

Once I move controller to some controllers sub folder, router is not loading controller at all. (there's not compile errors)

Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: The Go tools only allow a 1 directory per package, and vice versa. Why do you need multiple directories?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't have the initialization code for your other controller packages.

For example, if you have a `UserController` in an `admin` package, like `admin.UserController`, you should also have one `init()` func in that `admin` package, that looks something like:

```
func init() {
    beego.Router("/admin/user", &admin.UserController{})
    // any other controllers register here ...
}
```

Also, make sure to import the controller package in your main package, probably as an underscore import if there is nothing directly using it:

```
import (
    _ "github.com/foo/bar/controllers/admin"
)
```